# Python - How to convert an XML file containing XADES signatures to HTML using XSLT?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to use python to convert an XML file to HTML having an XSL file. I found this code that works for some cases:

```
def xml2html(xml_filename: str, xsl_filename: str, save_path: str):
  parser = ET.XMLParser(huge_tree=True, encoding='utf-8', recover=True)
  dom = ET.parse(xml_filename, parser)
  xslt = ET.parse(xsl_filename, parser)
  transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
  newdom = transform(dom)
  with open(save_path, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(ET.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True))
```

The code works for files without signatures. Unfortunately for files containing signatures, the resulting html contains almost no content. Files that do not work include, for example, such tags:

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
<ds:SignedInfo
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
<ds:Reference 
<ds:DigestValue>
<ds:SignatureValue
<ds:KeyInfo><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate
<xades:SigningCertificate>
</xades:IssuerSerial>
</xades:Cert>
</xades:SigningCertificate>
</xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
<xades:SignedDataObjectProperties/>
</xades:SignedProperties>
```

Some files do not contain any content at all that I would be able to read in xml. They contain only similar tags to the above and encoded strings. Probably the content is encoded.
However, I know that converting them is possible because I found a repository on github that has a link to a page where I was able to convert such files. Here is the link https://github.com/wlodekf/sprawozdania. The code is written in javascript and the XSLTProcessor class is used. I don't know if this class or something else is responsible for decoding the contents of these files. I would like to know if it is possible to do this in python, and if so what step was missing from my solution.

Comment: Maybe the code has problems with XML namespaces. But without a [mcve] it's hard to tell what _exactly_ makes a difference.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upload files that don't work for me because I'm not sure if I can share them. I also have no idea how I could create such a non-working similar file myself.